# Excel VBA check if a cell contains a string when data is mixed

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that contains both numeric and string values

```
Name Code 

Bob   1

Alice 2

Bob   33AL

Dan   AFAL

Alert  AL99

Bob    ALP
```

I want to select names where the "Code" column contains "AL" somewhere.

If I do

```
 If InStr(0, Cells(j, Code_column).Value, "AL", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
```

then my loop doesn't run because of the numeric values at some points in the column.

I have tried

```
 If InStr(0, CStr(Cells(j, Code_column).Value), "AL", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
```

but I am getting the same error. What should I try? A pre-loop checking if it is numeric?

Comment: `If InStr(1, Cells(j, Code_column).Value, "AL", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then` works for me.

Comment: Use an AutoFilter to do this and avoid looping.

Comment: @brettdj can you tell me how to do that? Incidentally, I am looping to create an array so I could later autofilter copy and paste. I need to split the data in 5 ways. If it contains "AL" then separate, if not if it satisfies criteria 2 then separate, if not.... and so on sequentially across different criteria. So not only do I need to filter records that have "AL" , I need to keep track of records that don't have "AL" for later filtering.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am gonna try staring at 1 and tell you what happened.

Comment: If you want to follow the autofilter example as @brettdj suggested then this will get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s

Comment: @SiddharthRout your code is working, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code something like this for data in Columns `A:B` of the active sheet

You can do the same thing manually without code

Then in both cases work with the output (plus then reverse the logic for your second criteria)

```
Sub CookHooker()
Dim rng As Range
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*AL*", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```